# Highly Stylized Number Input

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to find style rules for a `<input type='number'>` that will get me as close to the following picture as possible.

[image]

But I have not found a way to place the arrows vertically as in the picture. The only other thing I can think of is creating two buttons with the above shapes and then using javascript to modify the value from event listeners. However, such an approach would complicate things. I'm hoping there is a more elegant css approach.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What does your current code look like?

Comment: I don't think you can, and seems like dealing with all of the browser inconsistencies in trying to do that would be way more complicated than just doing it in javascript. jqueryUI has a method for it https://jqueryui.com/spinner/

Comment: Would styling it with a background image that has the arrows be good enough?

Comment: @alfredo I might be open to that solution, never thought of that. Sounds like a good lead though.

Comment: @ArashHowaida Glad to be of help.